# How to pass a value to other screen while pressing one of the Swipout buttons in React-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React-native project, inside one class I have declared buttons- Edit and Delete inside **Swipout** which I have used for render items of a **Flatlist**. Here's the code of my entire **renderItem** function which contains the **Swipout** buttons-

```
    renderItem = ({item}) => {
    let a = this.getStatusIcon(item.category);
    console.log(a);

    let swipeBtns = [{
      text: 'Edit',
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      underlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1, 0.6)',
      onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('UpdateNotes',
      NOTE_ID = item.id,
      ),
      autoClose: true
    },

    {
      text: 'Delete',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      underlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1, 0.6)',
      onPress: () => { this.delete(item.id) },
      autoClose: true
    }

  ];

    return(

      <Swipeout right={swipeBtns}
      backgroundColor= 'transparent'>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsNote', {
        JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item: item.id,
      })}
          >


        <View style={{width:'100%'}}>

            <Text style={{ textAlign:'right', marginRight:10}}>{item.timestamp}</Text>

        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>

        <Image style={{width:50, height:50, marginLeft:10, marginBottom:5, marginTop:5, marginRight:5}}
                      source={{uri: a}}
              />

            <View >
                <Text style={{fontSize:18, fontStyle:'normal', fontWeight:'bold', color:'#2c3e50', marginBottom:5}}>
                {this.getCategoryTitle(item.status)}
                </Text>

                <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'#7f8c8d', marginBottom:5, width:250}}>
                  {item.title}
                </Text>
            </View>

        </View>


        </View>


      </TouchableOpacity>

      </Swipeout>

    )
  }
```

Now the problem is-
I want to pass one value while pressing the Edit Button inside the Swipout as you can see in the above code I have used onPress on Edit clicking-

```
 onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('UpdateNotes',
      NOTE_ID = item.id,
      )
```

After passing these value in the next screen(**UpdateNotes**) , I have used the following code inside the **componentDidMount** function like below-

```
  this.setState({
    noteId:(
     this.props.navigation.state.params.NOTE_ID
     ? this.props.navigation.state.params.NOTE_ID
     : 'No Value Passed'
    )
  })
```

While, I am printing this **NOTE_ID** value in the second screen it is always showing the default value: **No Value Passed** . As i passed the some other value from the first screen on the edit press , it should not be the default value. So, I am not getting whether there is mistake of passing the value while pressing the buttons of the **Swipout** or something else.

It would be very nice if someone helps to figure out what's the problem and solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Hope it will help you

From

```
onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('UpdateNotes',
          NOTE_ID = item.id,
          )
```

To

```
onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('UpdateNotes',{NOTE_ID : item.id}
      )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. but can you explain why declaration like this- {NOTE_ID : item.id}  is necessary?

Comment: We have to pass data as an object in navigation.